# Как выравнять изображение по горизонтали?

Tags: html, css

Имеется код:

```css
.card .img-card {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.card {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class='card'>
  <img class='img-carg' src="//picsum.photos/200/300"></img>
</div>
```

Как выравнять `img-card` по центру `card`?

Answer (score 1):

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='card'>
  <img class='img-carg' src="//picsum.photos/200">
</div>
```